# Linux memory acquisition issues

Tags: linux, forensics, memory

I am reaching out for possible assistance regarding memory acquisition of a linux system.

As of yet I have been unable to either acquire or inspect the memory dump with known tools.

The following memory acquisition tools have been used; [LiME](https://github.com/504ensicsLabs/LiME) & [linpmem](http://blog.rekall-forensic.com/2016/05/the-pmem-suite-of-memory-acquisition.html?m=1).

While I can retrieve and analyze a memory grab from the same system while booted to a live linux env. I have been unable to perform the same successful analysis from the installed system.

There is a rootkit making use of anti-forensic methods, it either subverts the memory acquisition when using lime, or crashes when using pmem's direct memory acquisition.

While I have read some of the latest published articles regarding memory aquisition; [anti-forensic resilient memory aquisition](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1742287613000583), I have up to this point been unsuccessful.

Perhaps I can solicit some assistance, thanks in advance.

Here is some details on the system as well as info regarding the segfaults incurring during acquisition.

```
$ uname -a
Linux x80h 4.13.0-37-generic #42~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Mar 7 16:03:28 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

````
$ cat /etc/*release*
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=16.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=xenial
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="16.04.4 LTS (Xenial Xerus)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS"
VERSION_ID="16.04"
HOME_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
VERSION_CODENAME=xenial
UBUNTU_CODENAME=xenial
```

Here is the stack error that pops up in `dmesg`
```
[52849.103024] usercopy: kernel memory exposure attempt detected from ffff95699500c000 (radix_tree_node) (4096 bytes)
[52849.103029] ------------[ cut here ]------------
[52849.103030] kernel BUG at /build/linux-hwe-qx9Tq0/linux-hwe-4.13.0/mm/usercopy.c:72!
[52849.103047] invalid opcode: 0000 [#6] SMP PTI
[52849.104093] Modules linked in: pmem(OE) binfmt_misc pci_stub vboxpci(OE) vboxnetadp(OE) vboxnetflt(OE) vboxdrv(OE) nls_iso8859_1 snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic snd_hda_intel intel_rapl snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core snd_hwdep x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm_intel arc4 thinkpad_acpi snd_pcm kvm nvram hci_uart snd_seq_midi iwlmvm snd_seq_midi_event mac80211 snd_rawmidi btbcm snd_seq snd_seq_device snd_timer irqbypass rtsx_pci_ms memstick ucsi_acpi serdev snd intel_cstate typec_ucsi iwlwifi intel_rapl_perf cfg80211 wmi_bmof mei_me btqca input_leds joydev serio_raw typec soundcore shpchp idma64 btintel virt_dma intel_pch_thermal mei intel_lpss_pci bluetooth intel_lpss_acpi ecdh_generic intel_lpss tpm_crb ipt_REJECT nf_reject_ipv4 acpi_pad nf_log_ipv4 nf_log_common
[52849.108995]  mac_hid xt_LOG xt_multiport xt_limit xt_tcpudp nf_conntrack_ipv4 nf_defrag_ipv4 xt_addrtype xt_conntrack ip6_tables nf_conntrack_netbios_ns nf_conntrack_broadcast nf_nat_ftp nf_nat nf_conntrack_ftp nf_conntrack parport_pc libcrc32c ppdev iptable_filter lp ip_tables x_tables parport autofs4 algif_skcipher af_alg dm_crypt i915 crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel pcbc rtsx_pci_sdmmc uas aesni_intel usb_storage aes_x86_64 i2c_algo_bit crypto_simd glue_helper e1000e drm_kms_helper cryptd syscopyarea psmouse ptp sysfillrect sysimgblt ahci pps_core fb_sys_fops rtsx_pci libahci drm wmi i2c_hid pinctrl_sunrisepoint hid pinctrl_intel video [last unloaded: pmem]
[52849.112902] CPU: 2 PID: 13827 Comm: dcfldd Tainted: G      D    OE   4.13.0-37-generic #42~16.04.1-Ubuntu
[52849.114444] Hardware name: LENOVO 20HKCTO1WW/20HKCTO1WW, BIOS N1TET46W (1.20 ) 02/26/2018
[52849.115786] task: ffff9579a3e6df00 task.stack: ffffa416863f8000
[52849.117106] RIP: 0010:__check_object_size+0x6e/0x1a0
[52849.118373] RSP: 0018:ffffa416863fbe28 EFLAGS: 00010282
[52849.119636] RAX: 0000000000000066 RBX: 0000000000001000 RCX: 0000000000000000
[52849.120939] RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: ffff957a1f496578 RDI: ffff957a1f496578
[52849.122175] RBP: ffffa416863fbe48 R08: 0000000000019270 R09: 0000000000001beb
[52849.123488] R10: 0000000000000248 R11: ffffffffbf9491ed R12: 0000000000000001
[52849.125067] R13: ffff95699500d000 R14: ffff95699500c000 R15: 0000000000004000
[52849.126430] FS:  00007fcd0b9d7700(0000) GS:ffff957a1f480000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
[52849.127841] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
[52849.129179] CR2: 00007f4d2a2edaec CR3: 00000010567c2001 CR4: 00000000003606e0
[52849.130452] Call Trace:
[52849.131715]  pmem_read+0x143/0x197 [pmem]
[52849.133027]  __vfs_read+0x1b/0x40
[52849.134195]  vfs_read+0x93/0x130
[52849.135545]  SyS_read+0x55/0xc0
[52849.136883]  do_syscall_64+0x67/0x120
[52849.138134]  entry_SYSCALL64_slow_path+0x25/0x25
[52849.139346] RIP: 0033:0x7fcd0b507260
[52849.140624] RSP: 002b:00007fff87020908 EFLAGS: 00000246 ORIG_RAX: 0000000000000000
[52849.141820] RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 000055effb874380 RCX: 00007fcd0b507260
[52849.143085] RDX: 0000000000008000 RSI: 000055effbaf1000 RDI: 0000000000000000
[52849.144216] RBP: 0000000000008000 R08: 00007fcd0b9d7700 R09: 0000000000000000
[52849.145407] R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 0000000000000246 R12: 000055effbaf1000
[52849.146423] R13: 0000000000000000 R14: 0000000000008000 R15: 000055effb8743b0
[52849.147487] Code: 48 0f 45 d1 48 c7 c6 1b 4b 2c bf 48 c7 c1 8e 44 2b bf 48 0f 44 f1 49 89 d9 49 89 c0 4c 89 f1 48 c7 c7 60 4b 2c bf e8 13 63 e9 ff  0b 48 83 ff 10 0f 86 0c 01 00 00 e8 71 48 e2 ff 84 c0 74 6e 
[52849.148642] RIP: __check_object_size+0x6e/0x1a0 RSP: ffffa416863fbe28
```

I ran the memory acquisition through `strace` and was able to capture the core dump it initiated if that helps.

```$ cat /var/crash/cat _usr_bin_strace.0.crash 
ProblemType: Crash
Architecture: amd64
Date: Mon Apr  9 00:21:52 2018
DistroRelease: Ubuntu 16.04
ExecutablePath: /usr/bin/strace
ExecutableTimestamp: 1452699271
ProcCmdline: strace -o out.log -f dcfldd if=/dev/pmem bs=512 of=/mem-20180409-00:21:22.img
ProcCwd: /usr/sbin/volatility
ProcEnviron:
 SHELL=/bin/bash
 TERM=xterm
 PATH=(custom, user)
 LANG=en_US.UTF-8
 LANGUAGE=en_US
ProcMaps:
 55949c7ed000-55949c886000 r-xp 00000000 fd:04 1574278                    /usr/bin/strace
 55949ca85000-55949cac0000 r--p 00098000 fd:04 1574278                    /usr/bin/strace
 55949cac0000-55949cac1000 rw-p 000d3000 fd:04 1574278                    /usr/bin/strace
 55949cac1000-55949cac4000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
 55949ea2c000-55949ea4d000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [heap]
 7ff1c9117000-7ff1c92d7000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 6291697                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
 7ff1c92d7000-7ff1c94d7000 ---p 001c0000 fd:01 6291697                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
 7ff1c94d7000-7ff1c94db000 r--p 001c0000 fd:01 6291697                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
 7ff1c94db000-7ff1c94dd000 rw-p 001c4000 fd:01 6291697                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
 7ff1c94dd000-7ff1c94e1000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
 7ff1c94e1000-7ff1c9507000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 6291695                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
 7ff1c96dd000-7ff1c96e0000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
 7ff1c9706000-7ff1c9707000 r--p 00025000 fd:01 6291695                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
 7ff1c9707000-7ff1c9708000 rw-p 00026000 fd:01 6291695                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
 7ff1c9708000-7ff1c9709000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
 7fff8adb2000-7fff8add3000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
 7fff8add3000-7fff8add6000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0                          [vvar]
 7fff8add6000-7fff8add8000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
 ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
ProcStatus:
 Name:  strace
 Umask: 0022
 State: S (sleeping)
 Tgid:  13487
 Ngid:  0
 Pid:   13487
 PPid:  7765
 TracerPid:     0
 Uid:   0       0       0       0
 Gid:   0       0       0       0
 FDSize:        256
 Groups:        0 
 NStgid:        13487
 NSpid: 13487
 NSpgid:        13487
 NSsid: 5983
 VmPeak:            5224 kB
 VmSize:            5204 kB
 VmLck:        0 kB
 VmPin:        0 kB
 VmHWM:     1268 kB
 VmRSS:     1268 kB
 RssAnon:            292 kB
 RssFile:            976 kB
 RssShmem:             0 kB
 VmData:             192 kB
 VmStk:      132 kB
 VmExe:      612 kB
 VmLib:     1952 kB
 VmPTE:       36 kB
 VmPMD:       12 kB
 VmSwap:               0 kB
 HugetlbPages:         0 kB
 Threads:       1
 SigQ:  0/256640
 SigPnd:        0000000000000000
 ShdPnd:        0000000000000000
 SigBlk:        0000000000000000
 SigIgn:        0000000000305007
 SigCgt:        0000000000000000
 CapInh:        0000000000000000
 CapPrm:        0000003fffffffff
 CapEff:        0000003fffffffff
 CapBnd:        0000003fffffffff
 CapAmb:        0000000000000000
 NoNewPrivs:    0
 Seccomp:       0
 Cpus_allowed:  ff
 Cpus_allowed_list:     0-7
 Mems_allowed:  00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000001
 Mems_allowed_list:     0
 voluntary_ctxt_switches:       2755031
 nonvoluntary_ctxt_switches:    2872
Signal: 11
Uname: Linux 4.13.0-37-generic x86_64
UserGroups: 
_LogindSession: c2
CoreDump: base64
 H4sICAAAAAAC/0NvcmVEdW1wAA==
````

Comment: does the volatility imageinfo plugin provide anything useful?

Comment: Depends on if I run it on a memory snap of a live from CD system or from the running system. I of course built the necessary dwarf and profile for each

Comment: Could you provide kernel and distribution info of the actual linux system?

Comment: Kernel 4.13.0-37-generic on Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS (Xenial  Xerus)

Comment: I found a previous [comment](https://github.com/google/rekall-profiles/issues/21#issuecomment-351250977) regarding  a bug report that I did not think about with regards to the `CONFIG_RANDOMIZED_MEMORY` kernel option and limitations of `dcfldd`. Trying another memory dump using that method

Comment: Still no dice. I even moved to trying `rekall` from google. With this framework I was able to inspect some of the memory but the filesystem, network sockets & process list (the important) stuff was still not available. The only way to inspect those particular items is to rebuild from memory segment snaps using gdb or mdb.